# Selecting a LIKE data group but defining a row as last

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I am trying to select the values `LIKE '%Pro%'`, but ultimately I always want `'%PRO333%'` to be the last selected.

This is my data:

```
userid:    text:
1          PRO11
1          PRO23
1          PRO333
1          PRO2000
```

This is my query:

```
select * 
from table1 
where userid=1 and text LIKE '%PRO%' --now when I get that column I always need to return PRO333 as the last column
```

Expected output to be:

```
userid:    text:
1          PRO11
1          PRO23
1          PRO2000
1          PRO333 --always the last
```

How can I do it, thank you all for your help

Comment: Do you care about the order of the other rows?

Comment: Can you write your expected output?

Comment: @Nick for others it doesn't matter so much, just this pro333 being the last

Comment: @user2407394 i wrote output, corrected the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include a comparison between the value of `text` and `PRO333` into your `ORDER BY` clause to sort that value last. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE userid = 1 AND text LIKE '%PRO%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN text = 'PRO333' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Output:

```
userid  text
1       PRO11
1       PRO23
1       PRO2000
1       PRO333
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/05395/1)

Comment: I think using `text like '%PRO333%'` in `order by` will be better as OP need: *I always want '%PRO333%' to be the last selected*  ;).

Comment: @shA.t you might be right; OP says in one place that but elsewhere *I always need to return PRO333 as the last column*. It's an easy enough change for them to make...

Answer (score 0):

First way:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
    userid int,
    [text] nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @TABLE(userid,text) VALUES
(1,'PRO11'),
(1,'PRO23'),
(1,'PRO333'),
(1,'PRO2000')
SELECT * FROM @TABLE WHERE text LIKE '%PRO%' ORDER BY IIF(text='PRO333',1,0)
```

Second way.I used ROW_NUMBER.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
    userid int,
    [text] nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @TABLE(userid,text) VALUES
(1,'PRO11'),
(1,'PRO23'),
(1,'PRO333'),
(1,'PRO2000'),
(1,'PRO1233'),
(1,'PRO234234324')
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(IIF(text='PRO333',1,0))) FROM @TABLE
```